# Save the path in custom property

Tags: python, customization, properties

I have added a string property as a path in the preferences.
What can I do so that this path is automatically saved like all other preferences?

[image]

The Property is set up like this:

```
# Preset file path
    Render_Preset_File_Path: StringProperty(
        name= "Render_Preset_File_Path",
        description="Enter the path where you want to save your render presets",
        subtype='DIR_PATH'
)
```

And integrated in the UI like this:

```
import bpy

def panel_render_preset_file_path(self, context):
    
    scene = context.scene
    myProp = scene.srp_props

    layout = self.layout
    layout.use_property_split = True
    layout.use_property_decorate = False
    layout.prop(myProp, "Render_Preset_File_Path", text="Render Presets")
```

Comment: Hello, could you add a little bit more information about how you setup your property ? If it's in the addon preferences it should be saved automatically like the other preferences

Comment: @Gorious : Updated the question. If I understand you correctly, I don't have to add the property via scene, but via Add-on? How do I find the add-on properties?

Comment: This might help https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html

Comment: @Gorgious: Thank you, now I could do it.